# How to start reading file from a particular position c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I am reading a file using `fstream` and `getline` functions. I want to give a starting position e.g. my file has 13 lines I want to start reading it from 7th line for example. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include<iterator> // for iterators
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string line;
    int start= 7;
    unsigned long int index;
    For( int z=1; z<=13; z++){
    if (f_node.is_open())
    {
        getline(f_node, line);
        if ((line.find("$EndNodes") != string::npos))
        {
            cout << "$EndNodes found file closed .... " << endl;
            f_node.close();
            return false;
        }

        // Point index.

        int i = 0;
        int j = line.find_first_of(" ", i);
        index = strtoul((line.substr(i, j)).c_str(), NULL, 0);//
}
```

}
[image: This is my file]
I am reading only indexes and I want to start it from 7th index How to do it?

Comment: If you want to start doing stuff with the 7th line, read and ignore the first 6 lines in a for loop or whatever?

Comment: @Shawn it cannot be done in this way. Any other solution is appriciated

Comment: "e.g. my file has 13 lines I want to start reading it from 7th line" Well, unless every line is the same length, reading and ignoring earlier lines is the only way to do it. See answer for example code.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't want to start reading at the 7th line, but at the line with index 7. So you have to read the lines, extract the index from the string and compare with your start line number. Since the length of the lines is different, I see no other way.

Comment: @Rene there is no way to tell code the starting position like `seekg and tellg`? I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @RamiFar Sure, you can set the filepointer to a position you want ... but ... is the number of characters before the first line with indexes starting with one always the same?

Comment: @Swordfish so I can only ignore characters not a complete line. My 1 line consists of 4 integers 1st one is index followed by a space and then 3 values separated by spaces. Anything I can do like I read index and oh this is not the line I want to read skip it go on next line read index and again skip it. Something like that

Comment: @RamiFar You can set the filepointer using `seek()` where you want. But if you don't know, to which position (measured in `char`s from the beginning) you need to set the filepointer, you are out of luck. Yes, read, check if its where you want to start, if not ignore the rest of the line. repeat.

Comment: @Swordfish can you please tell me how to ignore rest of the line. do I need to use `ignore`?

Comment: @RamiFar you can ignore the rest of the line using `f_node.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` which will ignore up to the maximum value of `std::streamsize` characters until it encounters a newline character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To discard some number of lines, something like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::ifstream infile{"myfile.txt"};
  std::string line;
  int starting_line = 7;

  // Read and discard beginning lines
  for (int n = 1; n < starting_line; n += 1) {
    if (!std::getline(infile, line)) {
      // Error or premature end of file! Handle appropriately.
    }
  }

  while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    // Do something with the lines you care about.
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Except with actual error checking and handling and such.

Comment: How `while loop` start reading from 7th line? I cannot understand it

Comment: @RamiFar The `for` loop reads and discards 6 lines. So the first line read in the `while` loop is the 7th one.

Comment: can you please help me with this, I have 4 threads, I want to read the same file in cyclic distribution system. Like 1 threads has to read line 1 and then has to read line 4 skipping next 3 lines over and over.

Answer (score 0):

*"there is no way to tell code the starting position like seekg and tellg?"* No. NL is just like any other character, it does not receive any special treatment.

You simply must **scan the stream, counting the new-line character**:

```
std::istream& seek_line(std::istream& is, const int n, std::ios_base::seekdir way = std::ios_base::beg)
{
  is.seekg(0, way);
  int i = 0;
  char c;
  while (is.get(c) && i < n)
    if (c == '\n')
      ++i;
  is.putback(c);
  return is;
}
```

And this is **how you use** the above function:

```
int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  ifstream is{ "c:\\temp\\test.txt" };
  if (!is)
    return -1;

  if (!seek_line(is, 3))
    return -2;

  string s;
  getline(is, s);
  cout << s << endl;

  return 0;
}
```